# Load gravity form via ajax using do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode, plugin-gravity-forms

I am reloading my form using ajax upon confirmation.

This is working perfectly and I am parsing my `form_id` to the action function fine...

```
// code to trigger stuff when forms have submitted
$(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, form_id){

    // run code for white label site editor form
    if(form_id == 12) {

        // reload our form
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            url: admin_ajax_url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                action   : 'gf_reload_editor_form',
                post_id  : post_id,
                form_id  : form_id,
                isAjax   : true
            },
            success: function (data) {

                // remove the old confirmed form
                $('#gform_ajax_wrapper_'+form_id).remove();

                // reload form into our site editor aside
                $('#site_editor').prepend(data);

            }
        });

    }

});
```

The above code is working great.

The problem is reloading the form using `do_shortcode`.

```
class WhiteLabel
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        // ajax reload form actions
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gf_reload_editor_form', [ $this, 'gf_reload_editor_form' ], 20 );
        add_action('wp_ajax_gf_reload_editor_form', [ $this, 'gf_reload_editor_form' ], 20 );

    }

    public function gf_reload_editor_form ()
    {
        // get the form id
        $form_id = $_GET['form_id'];

        // do shortcode to output gravity form
        echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="'.$form_id.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" update]');

        die();

    }
}

new WhiteLabel();
```

OK, so everything above looks hunky dori, that is because it is. I've tested my other custom `do_shortcode` functions and they output fine.

The problem lies with the `do_shortcode('[gravityform ... ]')`

You are probably wondering why don't I just use the `gravity_form()` php function...

```
gravity_form( $form_id, false, false, false, '', true );
```

This works fine too! This reloads a perfectly working ajax form.

The issue is, I need to use `do_shortcode` because I need to include the `update` property. The `update` property can't be used with the `gravity_form()` php function.

The `update` property is introduced using [Gravity Forms: Post Update](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-post-updates/) plugin which enables my form to update the current post, rather than create a new one.

So this got me thinking, when I am loading the form using the same `do_shortcode` method on the initial page load, I am using `do_shortcode` inside the loop. This is how the form must know what post data to get and pre-populate my form inputs with etc.

So I tried this..

```
public function gf_reload_editor_form ()
{

    // get the post id and set post data
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    setup_postdata($post);

    // get the form id
    $form_id = $_GET['form_id'];

    // do shortcode to output gravity form
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="'.$form_id.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" update]');

    die();

}
```

..thinking the the `do_shortcode` might think it's inside the loop. But still, this did not work either.

Any ideas please would be great thanks as I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could figure out how to get `do_shortcode` working was by using `WP_Query`.

```
<?php

// get current site
$args = [
    'p'          => $post_id,
    'post_type'  => 'any'
];

// site wp query
$oSite = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php if ( $oSite->have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while($oSite->have_posts()): $oSite->the_post() ?>

        <div id="gform_ajax_wrapper_<?=$form_id?>">
            <?=do_shortcode('[gravityform id="'.$form_id.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true" update]')?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    No site found. <?=$post_id?>

<?php endif; ?>
```